# Save UIImage at full size including transforms from UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have an image which at full size is 1800 x 2400 pixels. It's being displayed in a UIImageView at 450 x 600.

I have attached a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and a `UIRotationGestureRecognizer` to the UIImageView which allows the user to zoom and rotate the image which is working great.

I now need to export the image at the original size (1800 x 2400) with the rotations and transforms and I'm struggling to get this to work.

My code so far:

```
    if let imageView = imageView, let image = imageView.image {

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size)
            let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

            context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: image.size.height)
            context?.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
            context?.rotate(by: -imageView.transform.b)
            context?.draw(image.cgImage!, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))

            translatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        }
```

With the above, the rotation is correct but the image is drawn off center and I can't figure out how to include the zoom.

Graphics is very much my weak point in development and I've been at this for hours with no success.

Comment: Is it possible to save the image  and the transformation separately and then reapply them when you want to display it again?

Answer (score 0):

Never zoom the image itself because it's time consuming and it's not the recommended way.

Use **scrollView** for zooming and you don't have to think about your image size.Put your large sized images in xcassets. ScrollView has delegate features for zooming. It has some beautiful properties too just like this.

```
scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0;
```

So Better move your effort to **UIScrollView** and you will see you don't have to write so much code for that.

Comment: Thanks for the response but the zooming and rotating are working fine, the issue I'm having is outputting the zoomed / rotated image as a JPEG. Would a UIScrollView help this?